# Paths for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am attempting to get rails routes paths via nested resources.  I have looked under rails guides using link below:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

For instance,

```
  resources :users do
    resources :weekly_progress_charts
    resources :calories_journals
  end
```

i know and can use :users paths.  What are the paths for calories_journals for instance?

for example, user_calories_journals_path does not get me a list of index via "users/1/calories_journals"

What is the correct rails's RESTFUL paths for calories_journals via selected user:

new
edit
update
create
destroy
show
index

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am a rails noob as well, but maybe the underscores in the route names are throwing rails away? I am pretty sure rails uses underscores to parse the method you are calling as a result of a "method not found" exception. Try renaming your nested routes without underscores and see what happens...

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with underscores. Rails plays right with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
user_calories_journals_path(user) OR
user_calories_journal_path(user, calories_journal)
```

It will show the index view in `app/views/caleries_journals/index.erb.html` OR `app/views/caleries_journals/show.erb.html`

EricM is right, use `rake routes` in the terminal to view all routes.

Notice that you could have `resources :calories_journal` also and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rake routes` to see the paths.

Comment: ty, for answering my question, this command line is useful to show me the paths